# Cycle 2 Carousel with transition effects

Tags: javascript, animation, jquery-cycle, jquery-cycle2

I am using malsup's cycle2 carousel plugin for displaying configurable slideshows containing multiple elements per slide (using carousel-visible option). I would like to be able to use other transition effects than the default one, like fade out for example.

Specifying "fadeout" fx instead of "carousel" works but then the carousel-visible option no longer works and the number of elements per slide is always equal to 1.

Has anybody had this problem before?

In advance thank you!

Comment: `carousel-visible` is an extra argument for the `carousel` effect, so it's not available with other effects. What's he intended result?